# embedded screenshots are missing in the sandbox pages

Tags: sandbox, kaa

I've been using AWS AMI sandbox, and have noticed that many screenshots in the sandbox are missing since recently as below:
[image]

One missing file is at https://raw.github.com/hunch7/sample-apps/app_description/configurationdemo/resources/pic/config_demo_2.png?raw=true

Have the files been removed?

Thanks

James

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some links on the Kaa Sandbox 0.10.0 were directing to one of the sample-apps fork on the GitHub and are now removed.

We will fix this in the next Kaa fix version 0.10.1 Sandbox which is planned to be release soon.

Also, we will try to restore at least some resources on the GitHub fork as a fast workaround.

**Update:** The issue should be fixed now. Please check.